# Indesign: Paragraph styles and line aka rules

Tags: adobe-indesign

How do you change stroke thickness of rules within the same paragraph of your paragraph styles section?

I noticed extra rules were created below text, how do you get rid of the extra ones in paragraph styles?

Comment: Rule thickness is controlled by the Paragraph Rules options. No clue what you mean by "extra lines".

Comment: Mmmaybe what you think is one paragraph, is actually two, or more paragraphs? You can accidentally do that by pressing backspace at the beginning of a paragraph. It can end up looking like one paragraph, even though it's not.

Answer (score 2):

It could be two things.

1. Each paragraph can have a Rule Above and a Rule Below.
   Each rule can be moved by changing the offset field.
2. The Stroke may be styled to include more than one line by using a stroke style:
   [image]